# Is it possible to mark something as deprecated in typescript?

Tags: typescript, deprecated, deprecation-warning, typescript-definitions

I'm writing typescript definitions for a Javascript API with a deprecated method. Here's an extract of the documentation (they say API but it's just about this single method):

> This API has no effect. It has been maintained for compatibility
> purpose.

For compatibility purposes, I would also like to document this method in the definitions file. But if possible, I would like to communicate somehow, that it has been deprecated.

While my current issue is only about deprecation in a definitions file, I would also like to use this feature in other code. So the question is more general: How can I mark something as deprecated in typescript?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/390

Answer (score 431, accepted):

You can use JSDoc comments to mark deprecated code:

```
/**
 * @deprecated The method should not be used
 */
export const oldFunc = () => {}
```

Also, [this eslint rule](https://github.com/gund/eslint-plugin-deprecation) can look through the deprecated methods and warn about their usage.

Comment: FYI, VSCode has support for this `@deprecated` JSDoc tag as of v1.49 https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_deprecated-tag-support-for-javascript-and-typescript

Comment: Do you know how can this be used for values of union types?

Comment: It works, but only at the Editor level. What I need is a warning issued in the compilation messages.

Comment: @DanielLobo If you have eslint set up, you will get a warning/error, depending on the configuration