# Is it possible to show a compile error when importing a specific module from a npm package?

Tags: typescript

I want my typescript project to throw a compile time error when someone imports a specific module from a package. Eg:

```
import { moduleName } from '@package/name';
```

This should throw an error like `Please import 'moduleName' from '@other/package' instead.`. Need an alternative to eslint rule [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports).

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755711/is-it-possible-to-mark-something-as-deprecated-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks but I prefer a compile time error.